# How to Unit Test HtmlHelper with Moq?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, unit-testing, nunit, moq, html-helper

Could somebody show me how you would go about creating a mock HTML Helper with Moq?

This [article](http://dotnetkicks.com/aspnet/Mocking_ASP_NET_MVC_HtmlHelper_using_Moq) has a link to an article claiming to describe this, but following the link only returns an ASP.NET Runtime Error

**[edit]**
I asked a more specific question related to the same subject [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2485341/how-to-unit-test-htmlhelper-similar-to-usinghtml-beginform), but it hasn't gotten any responses. I figured it was too specific, so I thought I could get a more general answer to a more general question and modify it to meet my requirements.

Thanks

Comment: Can you provide some of the code under test?

Comment: @Samuel, relevant code is in the question I linked to in my edit.

Comment: I actually don't know a good answer (don't really remember details of c#), but I upvoted it in an attempt to get some attention to it =)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

What you can do is this:

```
HtmlHelper helper = null;
helper.YourHelperMethod();
```

No need to mock anything. Works brilliant for me.

Comment: This only works if you've written a helper method that doesn't use the helper at all, obviously. If you try to get to the `ViewContext`, `RouteCollection`, or anything else this doesn't help you.

Comment: This should not be the accepted answer. It only answer a single scenario and not the case that you have to use Html Helper. Like @MattEnright said, it will not help you if you need to use withing you test Html Helper to generate Action Link for example.

Comment: This is obviously a mocked answer -)

Comment: This answer completely ignores the reality of trying to actually use the HtmlHelper in the method you are testing.  Sounds like a good way to generate a NullReferenceException.

Answer (score 46):

[Here](http://ox.no/posts/mocking-htmlhelper-in-aspnet-mvc-rc1-using-moq)'s another article that shows you how to achieve the same thing:

> ```
> public static HtmlHelper CreateHtmlHelper(ViewDataDictionary vd)
> {
>   var mockViewContext = new Mock<ViewContext>(
>     new ControllerContext(
>       new Mock<HttpContextBase>().Object,
>       new RouteData(),
>       new Mock<ControllerBase>().Object),
>     new Mock<IView>().Object,
>     vd,
>     new TempDataDictionary());
>
>   var mockViewDataContainer = new Mock<IViewDataContainer>();
>   mockViewDataContainer.Setup(v => v.ViewData).Returns(vd);
>
>   return new HtmlHelper(mockViewContext.Object, mockViewDataContainer.Object);
> }
> ```

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. The object is actually mocked here.

Comment: I made a change for MVC5. Waiting on Peer Review.

Answer (score 21):

In MVC5, the `ViewContext` has an extra constructor parameter for a `TextWriter`, so Thomas' code no longer works. I added an in-memory TextWriter to get around this problem:

```
public static HtmlHelper CreateHtmlHelper(ViewDataDictionary vd)
{
    Mock<ViewContext> mockViewContext = new Mock<ViewContext>(
        new ControllerContext(
            new Mock<HttpContextBase>().Object,
            new RouteData(),
            new Mock<ControllerBase>().Object
        ),
        new Mock<IView>().Object,
        vd,
        new TempDataDictionary(),
        new StreamWriter(new MemoryStream())
    );

    Mock<IViewDataContainer> mockDataContainer = new Mock<IViewDataContainer>();
    mockDataContainer.Setup(c => c.ViewData).Returns(vd);

    return new HtmlHelper(mockViewContext.Object, mockDataContainer.Object);
}
```

Comment: To use the ViewBag I changed the method signature to `public static HtmlHelper CreateHtmlHelper(ViewDataDictionary vd, object clientData)` and the return row to `var htmlHelper = new HtmlHelper(mockViewContext.Object, mockViewDataContainer.Object); htmlHelper.ViewBag.Client = clientData; return htmlHelper;`

Comment: It is the best answer so far but it will not work if you have an html helper that use htmlHelper. For example, if you are using Html.action(...) this generate a null answer.

Comment: What is the use for `ViewContext` here. It appears that `vc` is never used.

Comment: @Blaise You're right, it looks like it's not used. Thanks for the heads up

Comment: You also need to set CallBase to true to make sure the ViewContext properties work correctly: `var mockViewContext = new Mock<ViewContext>(
              new ControllerContext(
                new Mock<HttpContextBase>().Object,
                new RouteData(),
                new Mock<ControllerBase>().Object),
              Mock.Of<IView>(),
              vd,
              new TempDataDictionary(),
              new StringWriter()) { CallBase = true };`

Answer (score 1):

To test disposable helper like BeginForm with access to ViewContext.Writer you can use this:

```
public static HtmlHelper CreateHtmlHelper(ViewDataDictionary vd, Stream stream = null)
{
    TextWriter textWriter = new StreamWriter(stream ?? new MemoryStream());
    Mock<ViewContext> mockViewContext = new Mock<ViewContext>(
        new ControllerContext(
            new Mock<HttpContextBase>().Object,
            new RouteData(),
            new Mock<ControllerBase>().Object
        ),
        new Mock<IView>().Object,
        vd,
        new TempDataDictionary(),
        textWriter
    );
    mockViewContext.Setup(vc => vc.Writer).Returns(textWriter);

    Mock<IViewDataContainer> mockDataContainer = new Mock<IViewDataContainer>();
    mockDataContainer.Setup(c => c.ViewData).Returns(vd);

    return new HtmlHelper(mockViewContext.Object, mockDataContainer.Object);
}
```

Comment: There must be something missing. I got a `System.NullReferenceException`. "Object reference not set to an instance of an object". Any idea?

Comment: You probably need to make sure `CallBase` is set to true on the mock object so that the properties are set correctly. You shouldn't need to do `mockViewContext.Setup(vc => vc.Writer).Returns(textWriter);` either.

Comment: That line `mockDataContainer.Setup(c => c.ViewData).Returns(vd);` should be `mockDataContainer.SetupGet(c => c.ViewData).Returns(vd);`