# How can I create reusable widgets and define the widget content in my view?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

I want to create reusable widgets for a web site created with ASP.NET MVC and Razor. Basically what I want to achieve is put some content in my view and have some HTML rendered before and after like this pseudo code:

```
@widget("MyWidget")
{
   This is the content.
}
```

`MyWidget.cshtml` would contain the widget layout and when calling `@RenderBody` from the layout it would output `This is the content`.

My current implementation requires me to put the widget content in a separate file from the view and I would like to avoid this.

In my view I can render a widget by calling `Html.Partial` like this:

```
<div class="col_6 last">
    @Html.Partial(@"Widgets\MyWidget")
</div>
```

The partial `MyWidget.cshtml` only contains the content of the widget and the actual widget "chrome" is placed in a WidgetLayout.cshtml that is referenced from the partial like this:

```
@{
    Layout = "/Views/Shared/WidgetLayout.cshtml";    
}
<p>   
    This is the widget content.
</p>
```

Comment: That's what PartialViews, EditorTemplates and DisplayTemplates are here for. I suggest you however, to focus on EditorTemplates, I found them quite flexible than PartialViews.

Answer (score 0):

You have to create an Html helper that you will use in a `using( )` block, similar to `using(Html.BeginForm())` that ads a `<form>` tag at top and `</form>` at the end

This has also is relevant and has been answered [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8292497/how-can-i-create-a-html-helper-like-html-beginform)