# asp.net MVC4 HtmlHelper Extension and Render Function

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

Using this stackoverflow thread, I created an extension for my HtmlHelper

[How can I create a Html Helper like Html.BeginForm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8292497/how-can-i-create-a-html-helper-like-html-beginform)

My problem now is, I created a custom `.cshtml` File with a `Accordion` Function. Nothing special, just a custom Function so I can render stuff.

```
@helper Accordion(string text, HtmlHelper html)
{
   <div class="accordion">
       <div><h4>Das ist der Header</h4></div>
       <div>
           <p>Das ist der Content</p>
           <p>@text</p>
           @using(){

           }

       </div>
   </div>
}
```

In this extra File, you can use the System HtmlHelper (via `Html`), as well as an Helper you get from a parameter `html`.

Now when I try to use my custom Extension ie in the Index View I can call

```
@using(Html.RoleContainer()){}
```

But in this extra render File, I can't call nor see `Html.RoleContainer` or `html.RoleContainer`.

How can I make the `RoleContainer` available in the extra File so I can use it in my `Accordion` Function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After looking into Intellisense, I realized that the `Object` in `Index.cshtml` is type `HtmlHelper<dynamic>`.

What I did is changing my code to

```
@helper Accordion(string text, System.Web.Mvc.HtmlHelper<dynamic> html)
{
   <div class="accordion">
       <div><h4>Das ist der Header</h4></div>
       <div>
           <p>Das ist der Content</p>
           <p>@text</p>
           @using(html.RoleContainer())
           {
               for(int i = 0; i < 4; i++){
                   <li>
                       @i: Test
                   </li>   
               }
           }

       </div>
   </div>
}
```

That way I can use the extension `RoleContainer` as you can see in the code snippet.

```
@ASP.cshtml.PostHelper.Accordion("Content 1", Html)
```