# Is there a way to hide html inside curly braces in an ASP.NET MVC Razor html helper?

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc, razor

This is the closest thing I could find to this specific answer, but doesn't quite answer it for me. [How can I create a Html Helper like Html.BeginForm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8292497/how-can-i-create-a-html-helper-like-html-beginform)

I have a current html.helper that hides (or shows) content based on the current server time. It's not really a problem, but an improvement I'd love to see here. So the HTML helper works like this:

Html.DurationHtml works like this:

```
public static IHtmlString DurationHtml(this HtmlHelper html, string StartDateTime, string EndDateTime)
    {
        if (CentralLibrary.WithinDatespan(StartDateTime, EndDateTime))
        {
            var writer = html.ViewContext.Writer;
            return html.Raw(htmlContent);
        }
        else
        {
            return null;
        }
    }
```

CentralLibrary.WithinDatespan(start,end) is just a method that compares the current time (or a provided simulated time) with the date/times specified and returns true or false.

I implement it like so:

```
@Html.DurationHtml("<a href=\"link\">Content</a>", "12/12/2015 12:00:01pm","12/12/2017 12:00:01pm")
```

This works and does exactly what I want it to do, very well. My hope for an improvement here is to take the content out of the double quotes so that I don't have to escape the double quotes. The caveat here is that I cannot have the content sent to the browser at all. I know I could wrap a container with display set to none, but the content cannot be sent at all as some of the info may not be for public eyes until certain times. Is there a way I can make the html helper work like this and keep the content from being sent to the browser?

```
@using(Html.DurationHtml("12/12/2015 12:00:01pm","12/12/2017 12:00:01pm")){

     <a href="link">Content</a>

}
```

Comment: You need to share the code for DurationHtml, if you want people to help you. Add it to the question.

Comment: thanks, I updated it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need a helper at all for this. Using quotes, the helper makes for *slighly* less code, but given how you want it to work, there's virtually no difference between that and just handling it directly in the view. Compare:

```
@if (DateTime.Now > new DateTime(2015, 12, 12, 12, 0, 1) && DateTime.Now < new DateTime(2017, 12, 12, 12, 0, 1))
{
    <a href="link">Content</a>
}
```

Versus:

```
@using (Html.DurationHtml("12/12/2015 12:00:01pm","12/12/2017 12:00:01pm"))
{
    <a href="link">Content</a>
}
```

The only difference is the conditional looks a little complex, but I'd argue it's actually better that way as the code is self-documenting, whereas someone would have know how to use your helper. Regardless, you could still clean it up a little and still have nearly as succinct code:

```
@{
    var rangeStart = new DateTime(2015, 12, 12, 12, 0, 1);
    var rangeEnd = new DateTime(2017, 12, 12, 12, 0, 1);
    if (DateTime.Now > rangeStart  && DateTime.Now < rangeEnd)
    {
        <a href="link">Content</a>
    }
}
```

Even though, that's slightly more code, to my eyes, it's infinitely more clear. Or, given that you're utilizing a utility method in the helper, you could just do the same in your view and actually have less code than you would using the helper:

```
@if (CentralLibrary.WithinDatespan("12/12/2015 12:00:01pm","12/12/2017 12:00:01pm"))
{
        <a href="link">Content</a>
}
```

Long and short, if you're going to create a custom helper, it should have real value. Abstraction is a trade-off between reusability and obfuscation of logic. For something this simple, it's better to just have the logic in place, as the reusability is minimal (it's ultimately just a simple conditional).

Comment: Very helpful Chris, and you're 100% right. I was trying to separate logic from the view as much as possible and lost sight of the simple answer. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

A Razor @if statement is all you need.

```
  @if (CentralLibrary.WithinDatespan("12/12/2015 12:00:01pm","12/12/2017 12:00:01pm"))
  {
      <a href="link">Content</a>
  }
```

Comment: This is very true and does seem to be exactly what I am trying to accomplish. I guess I got caught up on a statement I heard once. "If you're putting if statements into your views, you might not be doing it right".

I will go with this solution, thanks for the help buffjape

Answer (score 0):

You should be building the markup for your anchor tag from the HTML helper.

```
public static MvcHtmlString DurationHtml(this HtmlHelper helper, DateTime start, 
                                      DateTime end, string link)
{
    //Replace the below If with your custom condition.
    if (end>start)
    {
        return new MvcHtmlString(string.Format("<a href='{0}'>{1}</a>", link,"Content"));
    }
    return new MvcHtmlString("");    
}
```

And you call it in your razor view like

```
 @Html.DurationHtml(Model.StartDate,Model.EndDate,"linkYouWant")
```

Comment: Thank you Shyju, but the link was just an example of the content that will be in there. I use the helper to display general html. So sometimes it'll be a link, sometimes a paragraph and sometimes an image with a paragraph. It's not for a specific use, just general HTML.

Comment: @EHaltom You can render any HTML from your helper method